# Dealing with accents at a .bat script

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'm writing a script to automate IP configurations.
Here is a 2 lines short version of my script.

```
set /A octet = %1
netsh interface ipv4 set address name="Conexión de área local" static XX.%octet%.XX.XX 255.255.255.0 XX.%octet%.XX.XX
```

The name parameter is giving me problems, accents aren't represented well and the command fails.

I've tried saving it using utf-8 and others but nothing is working so far. Any idea?

EDIT:
----WHAT I'VE TRIED SO FAR----

- chpc output: Active code page: 1252
- Saving the .bat with ANSI encoding
- changing netsh for "%**Appdir**%netsh.exe"
- Deleted all extra spaces at the SET commands

Output so far:
netsh interface ipv4 set address name"Conex≤n de ßrea local".... and then the error

It's windows 7

Comment: Your batch file should be in ASCII text, not UTF-8. Which OS version are you using? Which font set are you using in `cmd.exe`? What is your current codepage, at the time you invoke the `NetSh` command line?

Comment: What is the output of the `chcp` command?

Comment: Do not put a SPACE character between the environment variable name and the value. `SET /A "octet=%1"`

Comment: I would suggest, if it isn't already, that you try codepage `1252` for your primary attempt. Your command should also use the following syntax: `"%__Appdir__%netsh.exe" interface set address name="Conexión de área local" source=static addr=xx.%1.XX.XX mask=255.255.255.0 gateway=XX.%1.XX.XX gwmetric=1`. It is worth noting however, that using the same `gateway` as `addr` may not be what you really wanted and the `gwmetric` is also optional.

Comment: I'll update the question when I have a moment to try all the suggestions, thanks!!